# How to make Table sort of thing which is in line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to find out the way to keep my table all proper and lined up but when the size of the variable changes, the borders change aswell. Take a look at my code.I need a solution to keep my table straight.

```
THANKS IN ADVANCE GUYS:) IF YOU NEED MORE DETAIL, ASK ME I WILL REPLY CHEERS
```

Comment: string format https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use formatting in `print()`:

```
fmt = '%-15s || %15s | %15s | %18s ||'
print(fmt % ('', 'POPULATION calf', 'POPULATION cows', 'POPULATION old_cow'))
for i in range(generation):
    print(fmt % ('GENERATION %d'%i, int(population_calf), int(population_cows), int(population_old_cow)), end='')
    population_old_cow = population_cows * survival_rate_cows + population_old_cow * survival_rate_old_cow
    population_calf = population_cows * survival_rate_cows * birth_rate
    population_cows = population_calf * survival_rate_calf
    print('', int(population_calf), int(population_cows), int(population_old_cow))
```

Comment: Thanks I tried your way and now it works brilliantly.cheers :)

Comment: Also just for explaination, is the % used as symbol for strings or something.If you don't mind could you explain just the first line please @acw1668

Comment: @TheUnknown The first line defines the formatting to be used, detailed information can be found https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#old-string-formatting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [terminaltables](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/terminaltables) or [texttable](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/texttable/0.8.4).